# Unable to open file for reading in typo3 direct mail

Tags: typo3, newsletter, typo3-8.x

I am using typo3 8.7 and direct mail 5.2.2 version. When I try to send a test mail, I am getting the error

Oops, an error occurred!
Unable to open file for reading [xxxxxxx/fileadmin/images/x11111.png]

How can we solve this error?

Comment: Have you found any fix yet ?

Comment: Same error here. I've updated direct_mail to the latest version (security update) - now I cannot send e-mails anymore with the same error like above. Have you found any fix yet?

Comment: Quite old post, but if anyone still reads this: I shared the insights of our investigation into this on https://github.com/kartolo/direct_mail/issues/226#issuecomment-1339396372

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to disable the option to attach images to the mailing. The error should disappear.
2. You should allways prepend the full domain to your mailing (e.g. `config.absRefPrefix = https://my.domain/`). When your mailing is send, the email client don't know where the urls are located.
3. I Think, if you fixed point 2., you can retry to attach the images to the mailing if wanted.

Comment: thanks rené. At direct mail configuration : "Bilder und andere Medien im HTML-Format einbinden = false"  Now it works.